# Mybatis 1:N mapping <collection>usage

Tags: java, collections, mybatis

How to solve this problem??
I want to Map 1:N through Mybatis
First, There is UserVo

```
@Data
@Alias("user")
public class User implements Serializable  {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1304191724943818097L;

/**
 * 
 */


private String uname;

private String pwd;

private boolean enabled;

private String profile;

private List<Auth> auths ;
}
```

Secondly,
There is AuthVO

```
@Alias("auth")
public class Auth {


private String uname;
private String role;


public Auth(String uname, String role) {
    super();
    this.uname = uname;
    this.role = role;
}
public String getUname() {
    return uname;
}
public void setUname(String uname) {
    this.uname = uname;
}
public String getRole() {
    return role;
}
public void setRole(String role) {
    this.role = role;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Auth [uname=" + uname + ", role=" + role + "]";
}
```

One user can have many roles.
my mybatis setting is here.
UserDetailsDao interface
public interface UserDetailsDao {

```
public User findUserByUsername(String uname);
```

UserDetailsDaoImpl
@Repository("UserDetailsDao")
public class UserDetailDaoImpl implements UserDetailsDao {

```
private SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate;

public void setSqlSessionTemplate(SqlSessionTemplate sqlSessionTemplate) {
    this.sqlSessionTemplate = sqlSessionTemplate;
}


@Override
public User findUserByUsername(String uname) {
    User user =  sqlSessionTemplate
             
.selectOne("com.legalcounsel.javaprj.repository.UserDetailsDao.findUserByUsername", uname);

    return user;
}
```

and lastly, Xml file is here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" 
"http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd">

<mapper namespace="com.legalcounsel.javaprj.repository.UserDetailsDao">

 <resultMap id="userResult" type="user">
    <id column="uname" jdbcType="VARCHAR" property="uname" />
    <result property="pwd" jdbcType="VARCHAR" column="pwd" />
    <result property="enabled" jdbcType="TINYINT" column="enabled" />
    <collection property="auths" column ="uname" javaType="ArrayList" ofType="auth">
        <id property="uname" column="uname" />
        <result property="role" column="role" />
    </collection>
</resultMap>

<select id="findUserByUsername" parameterType="string" resultMap="userResult">
    SELECT u.uname, u.pwd, u.enabled, r.uname, r.role FROM user u LEFT JOIN auth r ON 
(u.uname = r.uname) WHERE u.uname=#{value}; 
</select>
```

However, the problem is only one role can be used. For example, if admin has ROlE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN could be shown.

I think selctOne.(~~~) is the problem. so changed .selectList("com.legalcounsel.javaprj.repository.UserDetailsDao.findUserByUsername", uname);

but there is cast Exception.... how could solve this problem????

Comment: `<id />` inside `<collection />` looks wrong. You are telling MyBatis to use `uname` to identify roles. Try removing `<id property="uname" column="uname" />` and changing `<result property="role" column="role" />` to `<id property="role" column="role" />`. Also, there needs to be a no-arg constructor in `Auth`, I think, but there may be one already if it's working right now.